# How to find out why Javascript is downloading so slowly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, fiddler

I have an ASP.NET MVC project, which is running as slow as molasses.  I opened up Fiddler on one particular call, and found several calls where there's a lot of room for improvement, to say the least:

[image]

The blue lines I understand are calls to my controller, and I understand where to go to optimize that stuff.  But I see a bunch of green lines (which I assume means javascript), and those are also taking a heckuva long time.  I must assume that jQuery and Kendo scripts don't normally take 4-6 seconds to turn around, so there must be something in our project code that's causing the slowness.  But how do I track down what code needs optimization?

**EDIT:** @DaggNabbit in comments below points out that the slowness is because these Javascripts are being called with a cachebuster parameter, so they're being downloaded anew with every call!  But I can't see anywhere in my code where we're explicitly adding a cachebuster.  e.g.:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.web.min.js")"></script>
...
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/jquerymobile")
```

I'm really not a UI expert, but I can't see where the cachebuster is coming from.  Any other ideas?

Comment: It looks like this has nothing to do with javascript execution. Fiddler shows just what is being sent/received over the network. So the green lines probably show how long it took the browser to request i.e. the kendo.web.min.js file. Or am I missing something in the question?

Comment: What's with the underscore param on all those URLs? Some kind of cache buster? Why defeat the cache for static things like jQuery and Kendo? Why are you loading some of these scripts three different times?

Comment: @DaggNabbit - that's an excellent point - it does look like a cachebuster!  But I just searched my codebase for all references to "kendo.web.min.js", and nowhere can I see that we're calling it with a cachebuster.  Sample Razor code: `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.web.min.js")"></script>`  Any other ideas where to find where the cachebuster is coming from?

Comment: Thankfully my days of having to deal with .NET's black magic are long gone, so I really don't know, but if you're only ever serving this app from the web root you could get rid of `@Url.Content` and `~` and just use a normal path; I don't think it would get rewritten.

Comment: @DaggNabbit - please post an answer that there's a cachebuster in there forcing reloading of the javascript every time.  I'm going to post a separate question to find out where the cachebuster is coming from.

Comment: Also note that it appears that you're not getting a compressed version from the server. The current kendo.all.min.js compresses to about 150kb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that @DaggNabbit correctly identified is that the javascripts were being called using a cachebuster parameter.  I've invited him to post his answer as the correct answer; when he does so I'll give him answer credit.

Meanwhile, if you're interested in *why* the cachebuster was being inserted, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16439906/7850).

Answer (score 1):

For increase the performance you can use javascript closure and css closure these are responsable for binding all the .js files into one file and all the css files into antoher single file so that will increase your loading time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to bundle all the javascript into one compressed.js file and all css file into one compressed.css file. Which will reduced the time taken to load.

Currently, It takes a 4-6 seconds because js/css file wait for the other file to load completely and than make its own request to the server for his process. You need code optimization in your query when calling your controller on page load as well.

You will get free dll to compressed and bundle all js/css file into one compressed file.

Hope you get my point what i mean to say.