# Cachebuster parameter caused by javascript postback?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16395026/7850) I was trying to work out why my site was so slow.  Someone there answered correctly that according to the Fiddler screenshot below, all my javascripts on a certain page are being loaded with a cachebuster parameter!

[image: Fiddler screenshot]

As far as I can tell, all my references to the javascripts below are plain vanilla with no tricks.  Sometimes they are included individually and sometimes as part of a bundle.  The view itself is quite an intricate dashboard, with lots of partial views and multithreaded scripts to load various different widgets.  I cannot imagine why anyone would have thought to put in a cachebuster.

Is there some hidden tripwire that one of the programmers might accidentally have stumbled over, that would make us have this cachebuster?  Any idea how to read this Fiddler report so that I can tell which particular view is triggering the cachebusters?

**Edit:** By experimenting with renaming bundles and the calls thereto, I found that the offending file is `_Layout.cshtml`.  Sometimes it loads the scripts normally, and sometimes with cachebuster.  Actual code:

```
<body id="mainLayout">
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css", "~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
... etc ...
```

Nothing untoward about that, right?  So what would a view based on _Layout have to do in order to force all the scripts to use a cachebuster?

**EDIT:** the identical problem is described on the [Kendo UI forums](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/general-discussions/unique-id-added-to-the-url-parameter-if-use-xmlhttprequest.aspx) (unresolved at this writing).  Here's our javascript code that triggers the problem:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ('@ViewBag.Loaded' != 'Y') {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/CRCDashBoard/LoadCRCDashboard",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#mainLayout").html(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: We cannot remotely debug your project. Your MVC site prints statements where those scripts are to be included. The way you print these statements and the API's you use for bundling determine what code or configuration value to set to prevent 'cache busting'. **You** will have to dig into your project. Or you can have luck and someone will recognize a filename, parameter name or number format and say _"Oh, you'll just have to set debug to false in your web.config"_, but for now I think it's too localized.

Comment: @CodeCaster - My question has two objectives: One, to find out if this is a commonly made mistake; two, to get some hints as to how to track it down.  I'm very inexpert at javascripts and how they're included, so I'm hoping someone can recommend a technique for tracking this down.  For example, I wouldn't even know how to include a script with a cachebuster if I wanted to, so I don't know what code to look for!

Comment: Which files are you looking at? The system.web.optimization bundling framework appends a hash that should remain constant if the files are unchanged. If it is the kendo ones include the code that adds those scripts.

Comment: @CodeCaster - courtesy ping - please see my last edit

Comment: @MartinSmith - courtesy ping - please see my last edit

Comment: The code you have shown us is for `LoadCRCDashboard` though. This does **not** have a timestamp appended in the Fiddler screenshot. Are you saying that loads the other scripts? if so look at the result of the `LoadCRCDashboard` request to see the code that it is using.

Comment: @MartinSmith - `LoadCRCDashboard` appears in the Fiddler screenshot, line 2.  Does that help?  Anyway, based on the response to the question in the Kendo forum, it seems that this cachebuster may be caused by jQuery, when we call `.html()`.  Just not clear how to resolve that.

Comment: Yes I know it appears there. But the request for `LoadCRCDashboard` itself has no timestamp appended.

Comment: @MartinSmith oh, yes, `LoadCRCDashboard` does make those other calls to the partial views `GetCultureInfractionByType` etc.  Is that what you were asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually it turned out that [Kendo found it was a bug in their TabStrip control](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/general-discussions/unique-id-added-to-the-url-parameter-if-use-xmlhttprequest.aspx).

We actually already used a different workaround by restructuring the views and getting back the postback data as a partial view.  So either that or using their suggested solution (explicitly setting cache to true) could work.